# hemisphereLight and pointLight from threejs not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm new to threejs so I decided to follow a tutorial for a 3d Portfolio but the light does not seem to work, I think it's related to the source of light but i don't know the values which I have to tweak to make it work.

Also, another error is shown:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `frameLoop` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `frameloop` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei';

import CanvasLoader from '../Loader';

const Computers = () => {
  const computer = useGLTF('./desktop_pc/scene.gltf');

  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.15}
      groundColor="black" />
      <pointLight intensity={1} />
      <spotLight
        position={[-10 ,70, 10]}
        angle={0.12}
        penumbra={1}
        intensity={1}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize={1024}
      />
      <primitive 
        object={computer.scene}
        scene={0.75}
        position={[1, -5.25, -1.5]}
        rotation={[-0.01, -0.2, -0.1]}
      />
    </mesh>
  )
}

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
      frameLoop='demand'
      shadows
      camera={{position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25}}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true}}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls 
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers />
      </Suspense>

      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  )
}

export default ComputersCanvas
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using quite specific lights that depend a lot on position. First, try adding light, let's call it "wide", and see if it gets brighter.

```
<ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
```

Secondly, try to change the position of the lights you already have, I suspect that your problem results from the position of your lights. You can use Debug UIs like “Leva” or “lil-gui”.

https://github.com/pmndrs/leva

https://github.com/georgealways/lil-gui

As for this "warning", you can simply remove the frameloop. Because from what I know, it's good practice to leave the loop running. Unless you really need it...

And one small detail:

`frameloop="demand"` not `frameLoop=“demand”`